# Email editor with image upload feature Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, tinymce

I am developing an app for an Organization that wants to send bulk emails (newsletters).

I need to create an interface to compose emails with image embed feature. I can use TInyMCE. But I dont know what to do to upload images and attach them in email and send them properly.

I saw MoxieManager. But Is it compatible with rails and if so how to do it.

Please help me how to solve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could base64 encode your images and insert them into the content directly.
All you would need for this is a small custom plugin (which is not that difficult to write).

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) to dump them in an S3 bucket and just use `img` tags in the HTML part of the email.

The process would be

1. User uploads using TinyMCE
2. Controller attaches image files to the newsletter model whilst storing them on S3
3. Email send method does a substitution so that the names of images in the HTML text that TinyMCE added in the img tags are swapped out for the correct S3 urls.

Comment: Im using my own server to host the application and it has ample space. So can I upload image to my server and use that path in email? will it work?

Comment: Yeah, that should work just as well. Just use the local storage option in Carrierwave or Paperclip. As long as the file is web accessible, any link to it will work.